# Polynomials satisfying Similar Appell Sequence Properties

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, polynomials

Appell sequences, $\{P_k(x)\}$ are sequences of polynomials that have the following characteristics.

$1.  P_0(x)=1$

$2.  P'_n(x)=nP_{n-1}(x)$

Now I have found a few sequences of polynomials that satisfy a similar set of conditions:

$1.  P_0(x)=1$

$2.  P''_n(x)=-n(n-1)P_{n-2}(x)$

Naturally, if a sequence of polynomials is an Appell sequence, then it also satisfies the second set of conditions because

$$P''_n(x)=\frac{d}{dx}P'_n(x)=nP'_{n-1}(x)=n(n-1)P_{n-2}(x)$$

However, there are sequences of polynomials that do not satisfy the conditions of the first set that do satisfy the second.  For example,

$$P_0=1; P_{2k-1}=0, k\in\mathbb{N}$$
$$P_2=-x^2+\frac{1}{6}$$
$$P_4=x^4-x^2+\frac{1}{10}$$
$$P_6=-x^6+\frac{5}{2}x^4-\frac{3}{2}x^2+\frac{5}{42}$$
$$P_8=x^8-\frac{14}{3}x^6+7x^4-\frac{10}{3}x^2+\frac{7}{30}$$
Are there any materials or papers on such sequences of polynomials?  Is there something that generalizes these ideas?

Comment: Do you also want to rule out taking the even-numbered members of one Appell sequence along with the odd-numbered members of another?

Comment: yes.   that also.